# how can i fix the ImportError cannot import name 'get_accounts'

Tags: python, django

hi im trying out python and django for the first time and im trying to set up a simple route to display some data. The issue im running into is that when i try to run the webserver i keep getting this importError regarding one of the functions in my views.py file located in the accounts folder.
any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

django version: 5.0.3
python version: 3.11.8

Error - ImportError: cannot import name 'get_accounts' from 'accounts.views'

/accounts/views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Account

def get_accounts():
    accounts = Account.objects.all()
    data = [{"id": account.id, "type": account.type, "balance": account.balance,"transactions": account.transactions} for account in accounts]
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

/accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "accounts"
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts_list/', views.get_accounts, name='account-list'),
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts.views import get_accounts

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/accounts/', get_accounts),
]
```

settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    #custom apps
    'accounts',
]
```

Comment: last urls.py should look like `path('api/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),`

Comment: it takes several days to get used to django :D

Comment: :D i thought it would be simple like flask... haha